# SSIS Package with CLR Trigger

Tags: sql-server, ssis, clr, etl

I am trying to run an SSIS package which calls a stored procedure that invokes a CLR trigger. I am getting the following error message:

> **Error:** SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.
>   **Source**: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" HResult: 0x80004005 
>   **Description**: "The metadata could not be determined because statement 'UPDATE blah SET field = value' in procedure 'sp_MyProc' invokes a CLR trigger.".
>   **Error**: Unable to retrieve destination column descriptions from the parameters of the SQL command.

I am running SQL Server 2014 but the package was created for 2005. We recently upgraded our servers and are migrating the old packages which is why we are seeing this issue now. The package was working fine before in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: is this still an issue or was it resolved?